# How do i make a selection sort without using the sorted() method?

Tags: python

I'm making a selection sort, but without using sorted().

I tried looking at the source code for the sorted() method, to see if I could get any leads, but no luck there.

I want something like this:

```
list1 = [3,4,2]
list2 = []

<code that sorts list 1, into list2>
print(list2)
```

and list2 prints 2,3,4

Comment: please don't dislike; I will be banned. ;(

Comment: A quick wikipedia search could have even given you the implementation. More research first, and your qustions won't be disliked

Comment: If you keep asking bad, no-research questions, you're supposed to be question-banned. That's the system working as intended. The solution is to do your research first.

Comment: savage. just savage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort them without `sort()` function by comparing each element read in every iteration with the other elements in the list.

```
list1 = [3,4,2]
list2 = []
minimum = list1[0]  # arbitrary number in list 

while list1:
    minimum = list1[0]  # arbitrary number in list 
    for x in list1: 
        if x < minimum:
            minimum = x
    list2.append(minimum)
    list1.remove(minimum)

print (list2)
```

or other method but the result will change the original list.

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(list1)):
        if list1[i] > list1[j]:
            list1[i], list1[j] = list1[j], list1[i]
print (list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the selection sort you want:

```py
def selection_sort(list):
    for i in range(0, len(list) - 1):
        min_num = list[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list)):
            min_num = min(min_num, list[j])
        list[list[i:].index(min_num) + i], list[i] = list[i], min_num
    return list
```

But the time complexity for selection sort is: {Average: Θ(n^2), Worse: O(n^2), Best: Ω(n^2)}, you may want a better method.